# C# - Razor - Partial Login popup view, What To do? SSL Required

Tags: c#, razor, authentication, ssl-certificate

I have a dilemma but I am not proficient enough to come up with the best resolution so I decide to turn to this brilliant community!

**The Situation:**  I've build a news website. The website was built in MVC, C# and Razor views. The site requires the user to login. I am using a popup modal to prompt the user to login (using a partial view). Now, since the new Chrome I am forced to purchase an SSL certificate. So I did that. Then went ahead to install it on my server.

The site works perfectly fine BUT:

**The issue:** I have an in house analytics server that track users' behavior on the website. But the server is not running on a secure protocol. After installing the SSL the news website, the site was having issues loading the custom-analytics.js that reports to the analytics server. It pretty much stopped reporting any user behavior. (No bueno!)

**My solutions are:**

1) Isolate the login into it's own view/page. (I really like the popup and I don't want to isolate it.)

2) Buy another SSL Certificate and install it on the analytics server. (do not have experience with Apache servers)

What do you recommend I should do?

Please help!

Comment: "having issues" isn't descriptive enough.

Comment: I meant to say issues loading the script. like @caesay said.

Comment: *what issues*? You need to be specific in your question. Show exactly what errors you're getting. Show how you're referencing relevant scripts etc. Don't just describe your problem in general terms, show specifics. Read over [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question does not have a specific issue it is more of a dilemma and what would be the best option to go with. The most specific issue here is that the analytics script is not loading because it is not being hosted on a (SSL) secure web server. I corrected that statement when describing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

A SSL (secure) page, can not communicate with an unsecure page - as you have found. This is a security feature to prevent potentially sensitive data from being transmitted in plain-text. As a user, when i see the green SSL bar at the top, i know all of my data is being transmitted with SSL - not just some of it.

You either need to install an SSL certificate on the analytics server, or if you can't easily do that, host a reverse proxy (with ssl) somewhere - basically just a server that will forward all of the requests to the un-secure analytic server.

You don't need to buy a new certificate though, with a little server configuration you can get them for free with http://letsencrypt.org

*PS: There's no excuse for not hosting everything on SSL these days. It's free and your users deserve it.*

Comment: I guess I have no choice here. Because I do not have a proxy server and using a public proxy server does not seem to be an option for me. I guess if no one else recommend anything better I will be forced to to pick between installing SSL on the analytics server or changing the login portion of the website. I agree with you that the entire site should be secure. thx